# Loop through an HashMap with DisplayTag

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, jsp-tags, displaytag

I want to loop through an HashMap with DisplayTag.

I have the following code in JSP:

```
<display:table name="${data}" class="tableBody listeGEH_tableBody" uid="d" id="row" pagesize="${pagesize}" sort="list" defaultsort="1" requestURI="">
    <display:column title="Name" sortable="false" sortProperty="name">
        <s:property value="#attr.row.key"/>
    </display:column>
    <display:column sortable="false"   title="Selection">                                   
        <input type="checkbox" name="selection" onclick="javascript:addRemove(this,<s:property value='#attr.row.value'/>);"/>                                   
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

data is of type HashMap`<String name, Integer selection>`

But nothing appears at the table.

Thank you for your help